# System.Transactions.TransactionException: The transaction has already been implicitly or explicitly committed or aborted

Tags: c#, asp.net, enterprise-library, transactionscope

I have the following code:

```
private void MigrateInTrackingChannelsDbTable(Guid toSsoId, string ctid)
{
    Database database = DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase("TrackingChannels");
    try
    {
        using (DbCommand command = database.GetStoredProcCommand("usp_TrackingChannels_MigrateToolbar"))
        {
            database.AddInParameter(command, "@ToSSOId", DbType.Guid, toSsoId);
            database.AddInParameter(command, "@CTID", DbType.String, ctid);

            database.ExecuteNonQuery(command);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Log.Application.Error(
            string.Format("CPUserService: MigrateInTrackingChannelsDbTable failed with toSsoId:{0}, ctid:{1}", toSsoId, ctid), ex);
        throw;
    }
}
```

but get the following error:

> System.Transactions.TransactionException: The transaction has already
>   been implicitly or explicitly committed or aborted.
>   System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: The transaction has
>   already been implicitly or explicitly committed or aborted (Exception
>   from HRESULT: 0x8004D00E) ErrorCode = -2147168242 App
>   Domain:   /LM/W3SVC/819313558/Root/ToolbarBackOffice-2-129804733861185000
>   Level:    Error Logger:   application Thread Id:  1 Error Message:    Migration
>   from: efrat96811@edokleinman.com to efrat98545@edokleinman.com faild ,
>   session from: efrat96811@edokleinman.com Source:
>
> TransactionException: The transaction has already been implicitly or
>   explicitly committed or aborted. AT: at
>   System.Transactions.Oletx.OletxTransactionManager.ProxyException(COMException
>   comException) at
>   System.Transactions.TransactionInterop.GetExportCookie(Transaction
>   transaction, Byte[] whereabouts) at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.GetTransactionCookie(Transaction
>   transaction, Byte[] whereAbouts) at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.EnlistNonNull(Transaction
>   tx) at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.ActivateConnection(Transaction
>   transaction) at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.GetConnection(DbConnection
>   owningObject) at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnection(DbConnection
>   owningConnection) at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.OpenConnection(DbConnection
>   outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory) at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open() at
>   Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.Database.GetNewOpenConnection()
>   in
>   D:\Conduit\RnD\Server\Core\Dev\Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data\Database.cs:line
>   1168 at
>   Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.TransactionScopeConnections.GetConnection(Database
>   db) in
>   D:\Conduit\RnD\Server\Core\Dev\Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data\TransactionScopeConnections.cs:line
>   68 at
>   Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.Database.GetOpenConnection(Boolean
>   disposeInnerConnection) in
>   D:\Conduit\RnD\Server\Core\Dev\Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data\Database.cs:line
>   1194 at
>   Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.Database.ExecuteNonQuery(DbCommand
>   command) in
>   D:\Conduit\RnD\Server\Core\Dev\Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data\Database.cs:line
>   690 at
>   CPUserInfrastructure.Services.CPUserService.MigrateInTrackingChannelsDbTable(Guid
>   toSsoId, String ctid) in
>   D:\Conduit\RnD\Server\Services\CPInfrastructure\CPUserInfrastructure\CPUserInfrastructure\Services\CPUserService.cs:line
>   772 at
>   CPUserInfrastructure.Services.CPUserService.<>c_*DisplayClass8.b*_7()
>   in
>   D:\Conduit\RnD\Server\Services\CPInfrastructure\CPUserInfrastructure\CPUserInfrastructure\Services\CPUserService.cs:line
>   386 at
>   CPInfrastructure.Helpers.TransactionHelpers.RunInTransaction(Action
>   logic) in
>   D:\Conduit\RnD\Server\Services\CPInfrastructure\CPInfrastructure-Dev\Helpers\TransactionHelpers.cs:line
>   17 at
>   CPUserInfrastructure.Services.CPUserService.MigrateCPuserToolbar(Guid
>   toSsoId, String ctid) in
>   D:\Conduit\RnD\Server\Services\CPInfrastructure\CPUserInfrastructure\CPUserInfrastructure\Services\CPUserService.cs:line
>   390 at
>   BrandToolbar.Admin.ToolbarBackOffice.Toolbar.AccountsManagement.btnMTMigrate_Click(Object
>   sender, EventArgs e) in
>   D:\Conduit\RnD\Server\WebSites\Writers\Dev-Accounts-4.0\AdminServices\Admin.Toolbar\Integration\BrandToolbar.Admin.ToolbarBackOffice\Toolbar\AccountsManagement.aspx.cs:line
>   142
>
> COMException: The transaction has already been implicitly or
>   explicitly committed or aborted (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8004D00E)
>   AT: at System.Transactions.Oletx.ITransactionShim.Export(UInt32
>   whereaboutsSize, Byte[] whereabouts, Int32& cookieIndex, UInt32&
>   cookieSize, CoTaskMemHandle& cookieBuffer) at
>   System.Transactions.TransactionInterop.GetExportCookie(Transaction
>   transaction, Byte[] whereabouts)

Comment: Please refer http://support.microsoft.com/kb/919216/en-us?sd=rss&spid=9774

Comment: Are you using commit or rollback in some of your sp's?